# How to update the each record in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to update each records in the table using the Update script

query 1:

```
Select acheivementsId 
from Students 
where student_id = 2
```

Result:: 61 records// Number of acheivementsid

query 2 :

```
Select acheivementsId 
from Students 
where student_id = 4
```

Result: 61 records// Number of acheivementsid

I need to update Student_id = 2 acheivementid's  with student_id = 4 acheivementId's.

how to write the Update Statement for updating 61 records.

Thanks

Comment: you have tagged this with both mysql and sql-server, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you give us the structure of the Students table?

Comment: Are the `acheivementsId` values the same for all records for each student ID?  If not how are the records supposed to line up?.

Comment: the acheivementsId is something like 1 ,2,3,4,5,6,7.. ans so on..

Comment: Tomorrow I will test on my Sql Server and I'll tell to you the result.
I've tested on SQLite and go.....
Probably I haven't understood the problem!!!
But you want change the acheivementsId values of records with student_id = 2 with the acheivementsId of records with student_id = 4... is right? ALL RECORDS....

Comment: it looks your querys are to simplified because normally you should have something like `Students 1:n StudentsAcheivements n:1 Acheivements`. And what do you mean by update? do you mean replace or just add ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Students 
   SET acheivementsId = (SELECT acheivementsId from Students where Student_id=4) 
WHERE Student_id=2
```

Comment: That won't work. The sub-select will return more than one row.